# Restrictions on accessing users public playlists

Tags: spotify

I am thinking of doing a web app that uses keywords to query Spotify web API for public user playlists, and then do an online mashup with my own music retrieval system. Is it allowed? Can the playlist names and tracks be cached for the purpose of categorization.

I read through the Terms of Use and saw this:
"Do not improperly access, alter or store the Spotify Service or Spotify Content, including (i) using any robot, spider, site search/retrieval application, or other tool to retrieve, duplicate, or index any portion of the Spotify Service or Spotify Content (which includes playlist data) or collect information about Spotify users for any unauthorized purpose;"

Paul Lamere does something similar with Playlist Miner: https://github.com/plamere/playlistminer. But he is an EchoNest employee.

Comment: Unsure if this question is appropriate for Stack Overflow, given that it's not about solving a programming problem. Perhaps there's a legal Stack Exchange forum you could query. Spotify doesn't assist third-party developers with legal assistance unfortunately, we only advise that developers read the ToS and try to adhere to them.

Comment: And btw, The Echonest joined forces with Spotify early last year! :-) http://techcrunch.com/2014/03/06/spotify-acquires-the-echo-nest/

Comment: I know..dats why i mentioned it.